# Joomla ZOO get this item id?

Tags: php, joomla, zoo

i'm working in joomla component zoo. what i need is to render at the item layout this item id.

i can get the list of all zoo items id, but can't find out how to get $this('id')
i can't use menu id as i want this to work also without every zoo item have its own menu link..

i'm working in full.php in zoo app template folder

this i got for now.. it give me all items ids..

```
$zoo= App::getInstance('zoo');
$zoo_items = $zoo->table->item->all(array('order' => 'id'));
foreach ($zoo_items as $zoo_item) { echo $zoo_item->id; echo '<br>'; }
```

so how i can get only THIS item id?
thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You need to use item get method & pass vaild zoo item id. It returns you all the information of Zoo item.

```
$ZooItemInfo = $this->app->table->item->get($ZooItemID);
```

Also, you can check following files to know more about Zoo API's.

administrator/components/com_zoo/classes/
administrator/components/com_zoo/tables/

Comment: thx.. but this is not what im asking for.. i want to php give me that zoo ID.

Comment: You want Zoo item id only or all the details of the record?

Comment: @Adamo can't you get Zoo item id from from URL?